# Google Charts - Very Slow Loading Time

Tags: javascript, django, charts

I'm relatively new to web development and I like the look of Google Charts. I wanna load some Django data with it, but the load time is extremely slow. I have a simple chart here with only a single point. It takes 3-5 seconds to appear, after everything else on the webpage has already shown up. Am I doing anything wrong or could something be causing the lag?

```
// chart 
google.charts.load('current', {packages: ['corechart', 'line']});
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawBasic);

function drawBasic() {

  var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
  data.addColumn('date', 'Year');
  data.addColumn('number', 'Msgs');
  data.addRow([new Date('2023-08-25'), 5])
  
  var options = {
    hAxis: {
      title: 'Time'
    },
    vAxis: {
      title: 'Number of Messages'
    },
    backgroundColor: '#2C2F33'
  };
  
  var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));

  chart.draw(data, options);

}
```

Thank you.